# Change a vector of vertices

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, graphics, vertices

I have a class, `AssetInstance` that has a `std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices` that has its vertices. It also has variables `position` and `size`. When I want to update its vertices I was under the impression I could do:

```
for(glm::vec3& vertex : vertices)
        vertex = glm::vec3(translate() * scale() * glm::vec4(vertex, 1));
```

where translate is:

```
glm::mat4 AssetInstance::translate()
{
    return glm::translate(glm::mat4(), position);
}
```

and scale is:

```
glm::mat4 AssetInstance::scale()
{
    return glm::scale(glm::mat4(), size);
}
```

However when I run that loop it ends up setting every vertex in vertices to the same value, and that value is nowhere near what it should be. I know I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Just a side note. You should call `translate()` and `scale()` before the loop starts and use the returned values instead of calling them for every item in `vertices`.

Comment: Another sort of off-topic comment - why are you updating the vertices in your vector? This is an absolute perfect use case for vertex shaders. Your code literally applies the same translation and scale to every vertex on the CPU.

Comment: Works for me... Sure you didn't start with identical values for all vecs ?

Comment: I am updating because I need to keep track of their location so that I can do collision detection. Unless you know an easier way to do that?

Comment: I figured out the problem, it's with my functions that calculate the min and max of my vector of vertices. Does the > operator not work to full precision on GLfloat?

Comment: @LarrySellers: If you're doing collision detection that way, you can transform your collision tests into the coordinate space of your vector of vertices instead of the other way around. It'll usually be a lot less computational overhead.